# Remove node from xml file with xmlstarlet

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I have the xml file:

```
<CustomField xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <valueSet>
    <controllingField>Field__c</controllingField>
    <valueSetDefinition>
      <sorted>false</sorted>
      <value>
        <fullName>field 1</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>field 1</label>
      </value>
      <value>
        <fullName>field 2</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>field 2</label>
      </value>
    </valueSetDefinition>
  </valueSet>
</CustomField>
```

And I use the following command to remove the node with field 2 value:

```bash
xmlstarlet ed --inplace -N x="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" -d "//x:valueSet/x:valueSetDefinition/x:value[x:fullName='field 2']"
```

But it was not removed. Is any idea how I can remove it?

Comment: It worked when I tried...

Comment: really? I don't understand anything

Comment: Append a filename to your command.

Comment: Yes, I appended it. But it doesn't work too